# Efficient way to get unread messages count in twilio?

Tags: android, twilio

I am trying to get unread messages count for each channel of user.After referring [twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/consumption-horizon) I came to conclusion that I need to get all messages from all channels like `currentChannel.getMessages().getLastConsumedIndex()`.From that lastConsumedIndex we need to count unread messages.
1. Is it the correct way to get unread messages count ?If it is the only way.Now for only one channel it is taking some time to be initialized.I think it will take more time to get all unread messages count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Looks like you might be interested in the [`getUnconsumedMessageCount` method on the channel object](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/0.11.0/docs/com/twilio/chat/Channel.html#getUnconsumedMessagesCount-com.twilio.chat.CallbackListener-).

Comment: I could not see that method.By seeing doc url you specified I came to know that it was 0.11 release version but when I am trying compile like  compile 'com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.11.0'. I got error like Connection refused. I think that version not released.Thank you

Comment: You know, that may be because we just released a new version that included a name change. Check this blog post for all the details: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/programmable-chat.html

Comment: @philnash Would the `getUnconsumedMessageCount` help get an unread count for *all channels* the user is a member of?

Comment: `getUnconsumedMessageCount` is a method on a channel object. To get an unread count for all channels the user is a member of, you would need to loop through all the channels and call `getUnconsumedMessageCount` on each of them.

Comment: @philnash Would that be a performance hit? I'm building a notification tray, so I'd need to show unread count AND which channel/user it's from...

Comment: Well, you'd probably want to do this once you've loaded the channels, but after that first hit you'd then just listen for incoming messages on all the channels and update the notification tray that way.

Comment: @philnash One more noob question for ya :)

Since `getUnconsumedMessagesCount()` returns a Promise, if I'm looping through all channels, how do I figure out which channel's unconsumed message count I've gotten, in the then() handler

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, so I'm not entirely sure. But with my experience of async calls in JavaScript I'd be looking to bind the async result to the current context so that I could still refer to the channel object I called the method on. I don't know if that's how Android/Java works though.

Comment: @philnash Worked perfectly, dude you are awesome!