# Twilio chat - unread messages count

Tags: javascript, angular, twilio

I'm looking for an efficient way to get and update count of unread messages in twilio chat.
I've reviewed related Q&A here (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724548/efficient-way-to-get-unread-messages-count-in-twilio)), and the anser was about looping through the Channel's array and Message Consumption Horizon. Is it the one way to solve it? It's not a cheap approach from the point of view of perfomance.

The second question is about ability to update this count on the fly - so, is there a way to create a notification for user with event handler for incomming messages (not push notifications) to update counter of unread messages in real time?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here is the way I've used to update the unread count real-time.

Refer Channel/Conversation: For **twilio-chat** consider **channel** & for **twilio-conversation** consider **conversation**.

Listen to the **'messageAdded'** event of ConversationClient. So whenever a new message is added you can check below:

1. If you have any conversation in focus: match conversation SID & reset the unread count to the newly added message's index.
2. If there isn't any conversation in focus or conversation SID does not match - then find out the conversation with the message's conversation SID & increment its unread message count.

Hope this is helpful.